# app.vote(1,{ from: accounts[0] }) is giving error

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, metamask

I'm trying to vote for candidate from particular account, like : `app.vote(1,{ from: accounts[0] })`.

```
    truffle console
truffle(development)> accounts
[
  '0xA1d77380Cb26e30F336F7B45EdaFcE49543A4e53',
  '0x48C9ae2AE4f031DDbfE605A56C4B59CAB7b54383',
  '0x232fD7cb05Cd1b2849124466c4b14ff907b42DC5',
  '0xAB6B92ED799DFEBA0d5bf65137Bf2c97682Beae5',
  '0x3679b44250bBE27b287b0c07E6d8D16388bd7494',
  '0xB353311c017ff9b3E20aa52f76F53D20fd6EAfD4',
  '0x596a306BE6FE7bB18DFC9065A4f0a498cD74aF32',
  '0xef277ADa2dc83aF974832D33056B649016c76Ea0',
  '0x96D3ab6192566c74074FC11445B6b4e4640eF6Bd',
  '0x1E9d006DF1e0F9FB013D23aB3702AddcF0119589'
]
truffle(development)> app.vote(1,{ from: accounts[0] })
Thrown:
evalmachine.<anonymous>:0
app.vote(1,{ from: accounts[0] })
^

ReferenceError: app is not defined
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:0:1
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:272:15)
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:127:14)
    at runScript (C:\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\console.js:222:1)
    at Console.interpret (C:\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\console.js:237:1)
    at ReplManager.interpret (C:\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\repl.js:129:1)
    at bound (domain.js:426:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:439:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:726:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:219:5)
```

Can anyone please tell me how to vote from perticular account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before interacting with your contract, you need to deploy it first (assuming you're inside of the Truffle project your contract is in):

```
truffle deploy
truffle console
truffle(development)> let app = await YourContract.deployed()
truffle(development)> let accounts = web3.eth.getAccounts()
truffle(development)> app.vote(1,{ from: accounts[0] })
```

Comment: Sorry but,can you please tell me, what is ' YourContract ' in `let app = await YourContract.deployed()` , is it project file name or contracts name(in my case it is Election.sol) ?

Comment: Yes, without the file extension e.g. MyToken.sol => MyToken

Comment: but it is giving error `truffle(development)> let app1 = await Election.deployed()`
`undefined`

Comment: Try `truffle(development)> app1` after running the just said command

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it so others can see.

Comment: `truffle(development)> app1` is showing constructorMethods, properties, metadata, bytecode, deployedBytecode, sourceMap, etc. , is it the right output that has to come?

Comment: And `let accounts1 = web3.eth.getAccounts()` is
`undefined` , but now `app1.vote(1,{ from: accounts[1] })` is working fine , Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213870/discussion-between-nicolas-schapeler-and-krishna-veer).